# Win32 COM port data scrambled

Tags: c++, winapi, arduino

I'm trying to have my Arduino Nano send data via USB over a COM port to my C++ script, but the data I get seems to be out of sink. I don't know what the issue is.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello World!");
  Serial.end();
}
```

And here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char Byte;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;

    HANDLE hSerial;
    while (true)
    {

        hSerial = CreateFile(L"COM7",
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            0,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            0);

        if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
                std::cout << "Serial Port Disconected\n";
                //return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ReadFile(hSerial, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0);
            std::cout << Byte;
        }


        CloseHandle(hSerial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the what my C++ code displays:

```
roHdol!!HdWl
l e!ol
l e!ol
```

My Arduino is sending "Hello World!", BTW.

Comment: Trying to read 10 bytes into 1 byte is undefined behaviour.  Parameter 3 of `ReadFile` is the number of bytes to be read (10), but you only pass a 1 byte buffer.

Comment: i set it to 1, and it helped, but the output is still a bit messed up: 

Hello World!
Hllo World!
Hllo World!
Ho World!

Comment: is there a function to wait until the com has new data to read it?

Comment: Have you read Microsoft's documentation yet? [Communications Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-resources). Especially the sections on [Communications Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-events) and [Monitoring Communications Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/monitoring-communications-events).

Comment: ive read through a lot, yes i can always read through more, but most of it is outdated for the old c++ windows forms apps

Comment: I think there is some wait-for-buffer-ready step missing. I don't think Win32 provide buffered read mechanism for serial port.

Comment: hmm any ideas then?

Comment: @Whityj "*i set it to 1*" 1) Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66449366/edit) and update the question so that we all look at the same code. 2) It is *extremely* wasteful to open and close the port for each byte you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino code is correct.

The issues that I find with the C++ code are as follows:

1. Continuously opening and closing the port is a bad idea (the while loop executes faster than the rate at which you get the data - this will just lead to you getting garbage data)
2. Since you are trying to read a single byte of data, argument 3 of the `ReadFile` should be 1, not 10. Instead, if you pass an array of size 10 to argument 2, your code is valid.
3. You are not using the return value `dwBytesTransferred` to check if the read operation with the correct number of bytes was successful. After `ReadFile`, you can check if argument 2 and 3 match.
4. In my experience, when a serial device is connected, windows automatically starts buffering the data. Depending on your situation, you might want to clear the receive buffer in windows using the `PurgeComm` function.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char Byte;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;

    HANDLE hSerial;

    hSerial = CreateFile("COM7",                                    //Placed outside while loop also, check if 'L"COM7"' is correct.
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0);

    PurgeComm(hSerial, PURGE_RXCLEAR);                              //Clear the RX buffer in windows

    while (hSerial != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)                         //Executes if the serial handle is not invalid
    {

        ReadFile(hSerial, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0);
        
        if(dwBytesTransferred == 1)                 
            std::cout << Byte;

    }

    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)                            //Throw an error if the serial handle is invalid
    {
        std::cout << "Serial Port Not Available\n";
    }

    CloseHandle(hSerial);                                           //Close the handle (handle is also automatically closed when the program is closed)

    return 0;
}
```

I've tested this, it works, and my output is

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Comment: In case the serial port was opened successfully, the `while (hSerial != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` loop never terminates. In case the serial port wasn't opened successfully, the code still calls `CloseHandle(hSerial)`.

Comment: Yes. The loop wouldn't terminate. The user needs to kill the program (pretty much the same as the ```while(true)``` in the question). You are right, calling  ```CloseHandle()``` is redundant.

Comment: Well, *"redundant"* is somewhat of a euphemism when describing the situations where a handle is only ever attempted to be closed when it hasn't been successfully opened.